# Laravel Eloquent unable to read data from databse table columns with numerical column names

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a mysql table used for a Laravel model. The table contains some columns whose names are purely numeric, i.e. contain only numbers which are years. Please see image attached below.

[image: Image showing the table layout with columns that have numerical names highlighted in red box]

When I query the table using eloquent the result results returned are missing the numerical column names. Even though the values are returned, the column names are deformed and display as single digit numbers.

[image: Image showing how data from the numerical named columns is returned]

When using accessors, I'm able to return the columns with friendly names however I am not able to update the model columns.

So my questions are

1. What is the best way to read and update the columns?
2. I'm not able to change the column names so the only option is to find a work around in my laravel code.

Comment: Interesting issue; but makes sense, since Models are PHP Objects, and something like `$model->2022` is not valid (*"PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER"*). You _might_ be able to access these as `$model->{'2022'}`, but your best bet is changing the column name to something that is not purely numeric (if you can).

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is because you can't name php variables with names starting with a number.

So to update the value you will need to write setters in addition to your getters. You should be able to do that with Eloquent accessors and mutators.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Edit: After some test, I didn't find how to do it with accessors and mutators, but I came up with another solution who might be working given Tim Lewis's comment.

```
public function setYear($yearColumnName, $value)
{
    $this->{$yearColumnName} = $value;
}
```

Comment: *"you can't name php variables with names starting with a number"* - Sorta, but not 100% true. `$2 = 2` is not valid, but `${'2'} = 2` is, and you then have a variable that starts with a number: https://3v4l.org/ImTfV

Comment: You are right, I've updated my answer based on that.